# How to make 2.4212744961175E+18 like 2421274496117503233 in PHP

Tags: php, number-formatting, citrix

I am using **GoToWebinar API** and getting following **value A** which is correct but i have another function which takes it as parameter and gives customer list.

```
A = 2.4212744961175E+18 

B = 2421274496117503233
```

Problem is function is not getting value A, if i am using value B its working

Can any one tell me how can i convert A to like B so it will work.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the PHP code you have tried.  (Also is this specific to "GoToWebinar" and/or Citrix? ...maybe how they are related will become clearer once we see what you are currently doing!)

Comment: its simple array and showing values .. nothing special code

Comment: What can be given name to this string :  2.4212744961175E+18

Comment: Shrug. You can make it easy for people to help you, or you can make it harder. BTW, as you care about lots of digits, it would also be good to give your platform (linux/windows, 32 vs. 64 bit, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $var = sprintf("%f",'2.4212744961175E+18'); ?>
```

replace %f to your integer if you are not using float

Comment: No it didn't work, it gives 2421274496117503488.000000 instead of 2421274496117503233

Comment: @NaveedMetlo You need to read up on floating point numbers and how they work. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php is a good start, and then the further reading it suggests.

Comment: P.S. Use "%.0f" to not see the `.000000` at the end.

Comment: i used "%.0f" but its giving wrong number with last 5 different numbers. I went through every thing on php.net but could not get it. I also found similar questions on stack but no answer found from any one yet ... Its very disgusting situation to not get answer of this... :(

Answer (score 1):

Just run the number through [`number_format`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php). For example:

```
$a = number_format(2.4212744961175E+18, 0);
```

Or start using third party PHP libraries that deal with numbers. [BC Math, GMP, Math etc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.math.php).

Comment: No it didn't work, it gives 2421274496117503488 instead of 2421274496117503233

Comment: Well, you actually hit the limit of precision, so you have to start using third party libraries such as [BC Math](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) or [GMP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) to preserve precision.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution and that large value with + sign was coming due to large integar and PHP 5.3 or less versions have that bug which has been resolved in PHP5.4, i tested on 5.4 version and it gave correct output.

See this [link](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62263) for details

Answer (score 0):

Yea I was having the same issue, looks like you had to add that last argument at the end to make that value a string instead of a float:

```
$data = json_decode( $jsonString, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING );
```